# steganography image im image by using k-mean

Tags: image, security, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

When I hide an image within a picture using the ( k-mean clustering) technique, I have a problem when scaling ( entropy major ) appears. I have the measurement ( 5.6) even though the size of the original image is ( 7.6) it appears to be very little and I do not know where the problem is